# Run code after form load periodically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, form-load

I am developing a desktop window application. After form load, get some data from running machine and saved it to the ftp server in csv file and it shows that test completed. I want to run the same code which takes values and store on the sever after every one hour. How can i do it?

Console application and window service is not feasible solution because I have to show the form to the user etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the timer classes that come with the BCL.

See [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) on MSDN.

Essentially you setup a timer with an interval (how often to fire, in your case every hour) and with a method to execute when it fires.

Comment: I want to show the form screen first, and the it should run that code and on test completion it should a message that test completed and it will run again after one hour. After one hour it will run that code again and show the message again. Where can i put this code which need to run periodically when the application is running.

Comment: @NaveedQamar - Up to you. I would suggest placing it in a class of its own.

Comment: @Oded has given you a good answer. The timer object can be set to run at any interval. You then set the timer state to "enabled" when you wish it to start running.

Comment: @Oded it does work, but i have a followup question when it run the same code after 5 min ... and while the execution of code i try minimize or do other things application goes not responding mode. then i have to close it.

Comment: @NaveedQamar - It is impossible to tell without seeing your code. I suggest that you ask a new question about this issue and post your code.